# VB.NET Attribute seems to be null after assigning value

Tags: database, vb.net, null

I have a windows form in which I call another form to perform some operation:

```
Private Sub btnAddParticipants_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddParticipants.Click
    Dim addparticipants As New frmAddParticipants()

    addparticipants.movie.movieID = Split(lstSelection.SelectedItem.ToString(), " ")(0)

    Me.Hide()
    frmAddParticipants.Show()
End Sub
```

When I assigned the value in `lstSelection` to `addparticipants.movie.movieID` the debugger shows that the assignment is correct, but when I enter the new form code, this attribute is `Null`

I include here the `frmAddParticipants` form:

```
Public Class frmAddParticipants
    Private person As New Person()
    Private _movie As New Movie()
    Private role As New Role()

    Public Property movie As Movie
        Get
            Return _movie
        End Get
        Set(value As Movie)
            _movie = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub frmAddParticipants_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            person.readAllPeople()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        For Each listperson As Person In person.personDAO.peopleList
            lstPeople.Items.Add(listperson.personID + " " + listperson.name + " " + listperson.surname)
        Next

        Try
            role.readAllRoles()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        For Each listrole As Role In role.roleDAO.rolesList
            lstRoles.Items.Add(listrole.roleID + " " + listrole.description)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstPeople_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstPeople.SelectedIndexChanged
        person.personID = Split(lstPeople.SelectedItem.ToString(), " ")(0)

        Try
            person.readPerson()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        txtInfo.Text = person.name.ToString() + " " + person.surname.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstRoles_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstRoles.SelectedIndexChanged
        role.roleID = Split(lstRoles.SelectedItem.ToString(), " ")(0)

        Try
            role.readRole()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        txtInfo.Text = role.description.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim returning As Integer

        Try
            returning = movie.insertParticipant(person, role)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        If returning <> 0 And returning <> -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Participant added succesfully")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            If movie.deleteParticipant(person, role) = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No participant deleted as it did not exist on the database previously")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Participant deleted succesfully")
            End If
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The "strange" thing is that I have another similar form which is a exact copy of `frmAddFilms` that works fine. I include the code here just in case:

```
Public Class frmAddFilms    
    Private _person As New Person()
    Private movie As New Movie()
    Private role As New Role()

    Public Property person As Person
        Get
            Return _person
        End Get
        Set(value As Person)
            _person = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub frmAddFilms_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            movie.readAllMovies()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        For Each listmovie As Movie In movie.movieDAO.moviesList
            lstFilms.Items.Add(listmovie.movieID + " " + listmovie.title)
        Next

        Try
            role.readAllRoles()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        For Each listrole As Role In role.roleDAO.rolesList
            lstRoles.Items.Add(listrole.roleID + " " + listrole.description)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstFilms_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstFilms.SelectedIndexChanged
        movie.movieID = Split(lstFilms.SelectedItem.ToString(), " ")(0)

        Try
            movie.readMovie()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        txtInfo.Text = movie.title.ToString() + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "(" + movie.releaseYear.ToString() + ")"
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstRoles_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstRoles.SelectedIndexChanged
        role.roleID = Split(lstRoles.SelectedItem.ToString(), " ")(0)

        Try
            role.readRole()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        txtInfo.Text = role.description.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim returning As Integer

        Try
            returning = person.insertFilm(movie, role)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        If returning <> 0 And returning <> -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Participation added successfully")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            If person.deleteFilm(movie, role) = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No participation deleted as it did not exist previously")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Participation deleted successfully")
            End If
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I also include the way of calling it, which is exactly the same as in the other one:

```
Private Sub btnAddFilms_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddFilms.Click
    Dim addfilms As New frmAddFilms()

    addfilms.person.personID = Split(lstSelection.SelectedItem.ToString(), " ")(0)

    Me.Hide()
    addfilms.Show()
End Sub
```

I have checked the code about a thousand times and I don't find any difference between both which could make this error happen

Comment: Firstly, the word you need is Property, not Attribute. And if the code for assigning `personID` is working in `frmAddFilms`, then maybe the issue lies in your `Movie` class?

Comment: I've checked obviously `Movie` class but it is so similar to `Person` class, and it is well implemented as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is typo in your code. Replace this line

```
frmAddParticipants.Show()
```

with the one you've intented to call

```
addparticipants.Show()
```

Calling frmAddParticipants.Show causes call to the My.Forms.frmAddParticipants property that creates new instance of your frmAddParticipants form. And this new instance has no clue about your movie ID.